# Rails 5 with memcached caching issue, wrong fragment cache is sticking even if I clear the cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, memcached

I have a Rails 5.2 app hosted on Heroku with Memcached cloud used, I have implemented multiple caching techniques in the app but one part of it has been very problematic & I tried to fix it for the past few days:

Fragment caching in one view had a design issue that I have fixed & then  this ***design bug is still cached & delivered*** to users even after clearing the cache multiple times using:

`Rails.cache.clear` which gives me a correct output of clearing the cache like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.clear
D, [2019-08-20T08:42:09.459517 #4] DEBUG -- : Dalli::Server#connect memcached-xxxxxxxxxx
I, [2019-08-20T08:42:09.596603 #4]  INFO -- : Dalli/SASL authenticating as memcached-appxxxxxx
I, [2019-08-20T08:42:09.598383 #4]  INFO -- : Dalli/SASL: Authenticated
=> [true]
```

The design bug is fixed for a page once I clear the cache (from Rails) then reload this page, however for other pages the wrong cache is still there until I find that (incorrectly cached) page, load it then it won't be fixed until I clear the cache again ...

**It is now I have to find every single wrongly cached page**, load it once (with the bad cache) & then clear the cache for it to work fine (as if I am clearing cache for one by one)

What is the correct way to fix this for all the cached pages at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of expiring fragment caches, I'd recommend versioning them. e.g. instead of `nav_header`, you use a key like `nav_header_v2`. Memcached will automatically clear content that doesn't get used, so the original fragments disappear to make room for the new ones. You never have to worry about clearing the cache.

You can go even further and automatically include a git version ID on all fragment keys, so they'll refresh when the code changes, e.g. `nav_header_#{My::Application.config.git_commit}|`.

This is the approach [RailsGuides explains](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) and ActiveRecord supports it via `cache_key_with_version`, so you can easily fragment-cache views of your models without having to clear them when the data changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually tried using an env variable in the cache key so that I can easily invalidate old cache but somehow it mixes up & works well for some records & mixes up for some still 

For example:
`<% cache([ENV['CACHING_KEY_ADD_ON'], @product], locale: I18n.locale) do %>`

Also why (if you know this) is it not possible to flush the cache itself? I feel the clear command is only flushing cache on Rails but not on memcached

Comment: "I feel the clear command is only flushing cache on Rails" I don't think Rails itself caches, even in devleopment (ie it doesn't store cache data in memory, in the same process as the server). So I think if you're seeing something not flush, it's a memcache issue. You can try restarting memcache to confirm. Also be aware of HTTP caching as a completely separate type of caching that can confuse things. (e.g. disable caching in Chrome devtools or make calls using a command-line tool like httpie/curl that won't be affected by it).

Comment: What you've written above should work for fragment caching, assuming you're restarting the server after changing CACHING_KEY_ADD_ON. If you want to change it without restarting the server, you can try storing the cache key add-on in the database or Redis (with a small performance hit, but you can make it a controller variable so it's only retrieved once per request).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation, really appreciated, actually I was always using (cmd shift R) in chrome to avoid the browser cache & as you said I felt it is memcached that is not being flushed (which is probably the case, as in Heroku I have no direct access to flush it)

I have upvoted the wonderful answer & will accept it once we can try it, I hope maybe someone will say how to flush the memcached cloud also for the benefit of me & the community as well

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't use Heroku, so can't say, you might want to post it as a separate question. BTW I'd also suggest updating your fragments to show  "current" time (ie time the fragment was generated - like `<%= DateTime.now %>`) and maybe the memcached key array (as an HTML comment if it's a production system). That will help you understand if it's still serving stale fragments when you reload in the browser.